# objective-c json serialization exception

Tags: objective-c, debugging, exception

This is a three part question.

I keep getting an obj_exception_throw error on an attempt to serialize a dictionary - here's the line of code that is throwing the exception:

```
NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictJSONData options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
```

Here's the dictionary itself:

```
PA =     {
        "CUSTOMER_ID" = xxxxxxx;
        "GROSS_GROWTH_NO_YF_FLU" = 39385;
        "GROSS_GROWTH_ONLINE_DISC" = 394;
        "GROSS_GROWTH_SALES" = 56500;
        "GROSS_PROJECTED_NO_YF_FLU" = 35805;
        "GROSS_PROJECTED_ONLINE_DISC" = 358;
        "GROSS_PROJECTED_SALES" = 52920;
        "GROSS_SALES" = 0;
        "GROSS_SALES_CUST_PRICE_LIST" = 0;
        "GROWTH_MATCH_REBATE_AMT" = 3509;
        "GROWTH_NET_SALES" = 56500;
        "GROWTH_NET_SALES_NO_YF_FLU" = 394;
        "GROWTH_PROJ_SALES_NO_YF_FLU" = 3509;
        "GROWTH_REBATE_AMT" = 3509;
        "GROWTH_REBATE_PCT" = 9;
        "MATCH_GRTH_REBATE_GRTH_SALES" = "";
        "MATCH_NET_SALES" = 49200;
        "MATCH_PROJ_SALES_NO_YF_FLU" = 35447;
        "MATCH_REBATE_AMT" = 3190;
        "MATCH_REBATE_NET_DISCOUNT_SLS" = "";
        "MTH_GRTH_RBT_GRTH_NET_DISC_SLS" = "";
        "NEW_PRICE_DISC_NET_DISC" = "";
        "ONLINE_DISCOUNT_PCT" = 1;
        "OPER_ID" = xxxxxx;
        "PA_CREATE_DT" = "2014-01-03 05:00:00 +0000";
        "PA_ID" = 0;
        "PA_NAME" = "Copy of 8";
        "PA_STATUS_ID" = 2;
        "PRICELIST_TYPE_ID" = 5;
        "PRICE_LIST_GROWTH_SALES" = "";
        "PRICE_LIST_PROJECTED_SALES" = "";
        "REBATE_ELG_PROD_COUNT" = 0;
        "SALES_ROSTER_ID" = 20016;
        "START_DT" = "2014-01-03 17:56:12 +0000";
        "STATUS_PRICE_LIST_NET_DISC_SLS" = "";
        "STATUS_PRICE_LIST_PROJ_SALES" = "";
        "TOTAL_GRTH_MATCH_REBATE_AMT" = "";
        "UPFRONT_DISCOUNT_PCT" = 0;
    };
    PRODUCTS =     (
                {
            "DISCOUNT_DOSE_PRICE" = 8;
            "DISCOUNT_UNIT_PRICE" = 80;
            "GROWTH_DOSES" = 0;
            "GROWTH_PROJECTED" = 0;
            "LIST_DOSE_PRICE" = 0;
            "OPER_ID" = 20016;
            "PA_PRODUCT_ID" = xxxxx;
            "PRODUCT_ID" = xxxxxx;
            "SALES_PROJECTED" = 0;
            "SUGGESTED_DOSES" = 0;
            "USER_SELECTED_DOSES" = 0;
        },
                {
            "DISCOUNT_DOSE_PRICE" = 8;
            "DISCOUNT_UNIT_PRICE" = 80;
            "GROWTH_DOSES" = 0;
            "GROWTH_PROJECTED" = 0;
            "LIST_DOSE_PRICE" = 0;
            "OPER_ID" = 20016;
            "PA_PRODUCT_ID" = xxxxx;
            "PRODUCT_ID" = xxxxx;
            "SALES_PROJECTED" = 0;
            "SUGGESTED_DOSES" = 0;
            "USER_SELECTED_DOSES" = 0;
        }
    );
}
```

OK, so part 1: Any idea why the exception is being throw - do I need to set up my data differently?

Part 2: I'm not really savvy at understanding the information shown for the exception so if someone could break it down for me in simple terms I would greatly appreciate it.

Here's what I get when the exception is thrown:

[image]

and when I click on the exception...

[image]

Is there some sort of guide that can walk me through what I am seeing here because this might as well be in Mandarian for me. : D

and part 3: Why wasn't the exception logged in the @try?

Thanks a bunch!

Edit: Here's the print out from the exception in case you can't view the file:

```
0x1cb088a:  pushl  %ebp
0x1cb088b:  movl   %esp, %ebp
0x1cb088d:  pushl  %ebx
0x1cb088e:  pushl  %edi
0x1cb088f:  pushl  %esi
0x1cb0890:  subl   $2028, %esp
0x1cb0896:  calll  0x1cb089b                 ; objc_exception_throw + 17
0x1cb089b:  popl   %ebx
0x1cb089c:  movl   $16, (%esp)
0x1cb08a3:  calll  0x1cc3678                 ; symbol stub for: __cxa_allocate_exception
0x1cb08a8:  movl   %eax, %esi
0x1cb08aa:  movl   8(%ebp), %eax
0x1cb08ad:  movl   %eax, (%esp)
0x1cb08b0:  calll  *1722297(%ebx)
0x1cb08b6:  movl   %eax, %edi
0x1cb08b8:  movl   1721937(%ebx), %eax
0x1cb08be:  movl   %eax, 4(%esp)
0x1cb08c2:  movl   %edi, (%esp)
0x1cb08c5:  calll  0x1cc00a4                 ; objc_msgSend
0x1cb08ca:  movl   %edi, (%esi)
0x1cb08cc:  leal   1722253(%ebx), %eax
0x1cb08d2:  movl   %eax, 4(%esi)
0x1cb08d5:  movl   %edi, (%esp)
0x1cb08d8:  calll  0x1caee20                 ; object_getClassName
0x1cb08dd:  movl   %eax, 8(%esi)
0x1cb08e0:  xorl   %eax, %eax
0x1cb08e2:  testl  %edi, %edi
0x1cb08e4:  je     0x1cb08e8                 ; objc_exception_throw + 94
0x1cb08e6:  movl   (%edi), %eax
0x1cb08e8:  movl   %eax, 12(%esi)
0x1cb08eb:  movl   1718237(%ebx), %eax
0x1cb08f1:  movl   %eax, -2016(%ebp)
0x1cb08f7:  cmpb   $0, (%eax)
0x1cb08fa:  je     0x1cb091e                 ; objc_exception_throw + 148
0x1cb08fc:  movl   %edi, (%esp)
0x1cb08ff:  calll  0x1caee20                 ; object_getClassName
0x1cb0904:  movl   %eax, 12(%esp)
0x1cb0908:  movl   %edi, 8(%esp)
0x1cb090c:  movl   %esi, 4(%esp)
0x1cb0910:  leal   82373(%ebx), %eax
0x1cb0916:  movl   %eax, (%esp)
0x1cb0919:  calll  0x1cb047e                 ; _objc_inform
0x1cb091e:  movl   1718233(%ebx), %eax
0x1cb0924:  cmpb   $0, (%eax)
0x1cb0927:  je     0x1cb099e                 ; objc_exception_throw + 276
0x1cb0929:  movl   -2016(%ebp), %eax
0x1cb092f:  cmpb   $0, (%eax)
0x1cb0932:  jne    0x1cb0956                 ; objc_exception_throw + 204
0x1cb0934:  movl   %edi, (%esp)
0x1cb0937:  calll  0x1caee20                 ; object_getClassName
0x1cb093c:  movl   %eax, 12(%esp)
0x1cb0940:  movl   %edi, 8(%esp)
0x1cb0944:  movl   %esi, 4(%esp)
0x1cb0948:  leal   82373(%ebx), %eax
0x1cb094e:  movl   %eax, (%esp)
0x1cb0951:  calll  0x1cb047e                 ; _objc_inform
0x1cb0956:  leal   -2012(%ebp), %eax
0x1cb095c:  movl   %eax, (%esp)
0x1cb095f:  movl   $500, 4(%esp)
0x1cb0967:  calll  0x1cc3738                 ; symbol stub for: backtrace
0x1cb096c:  movl   %eax, -2016(%ebp)
0x1cb0972:  movl   1718245(%ebx), %eax
0x1cb0978:  movl   (%eax), %eax
0x1cb097a:  movl   %eax, (%esp)
0x1cb097d:  calll  0x1cc377a                 ; symbol stub for: fileno
0x1cb0982:  movl   %eax, 8(%esp)
0x1cb0986:  movl   -2016(%ebp), %eax
0x1cb098c:  movl   %eax, 4(%esp)
0x1cb0990:  leal   -2012(%ebp), %eax
0x1cb0996:  movl   %eax, (%esp)
0x1cb0999:  calll  0x1cc3744                 ; symbol stub for: backtrace_symbols_fd
0x1cb099e:  movl   %ebx, -2016(%ebp)
0x1cb09a4:  movl   %esi, %ebx
0x1cb09a6:  addl   $4, %esi
0x1cb09a9:  movl   %edi, (%esp)
0x1cb09ac:  nop    
0x1cb09ad:  nopl   (%eax)
0x1cb09b1:  movl   -2016(%ebp), %eax
0x1cb09b7:  leal   306(%eax), %eax
0x1cb09bd:  movl   %eax, 8(%esp)
0x1cb09c1:  movl   %esi, 4(%esp)
0x1cb09c5:  movl   %ebx, (%esp)
0x1cb09c8:  calll  0x1cc369c                 ; symbol stub for: __cxa_throw
```

Comment: When you click on the exception frame, try entering the command `po $eax`.

Comment: Is `xxxxxxx ` the literal, actual value that you have in a file somewhere, and treating as if it's a JSON dictionary value?

Comment: I can't read those screenshots. Post text.

Comment: No, it's proprietary info, I x'd it out just for SO - the values are what they should be in the dict, I've checked them.

Comment: H2CO3 - did you right click on the image and view in another tab?

Comment: What I would do: 1) Write the NSData out to a file and validate the JSON with PlistEdit Pro. 2) Get rid of the try/catch code. 3) Add an exception breakpoint. 4) On break click continue a couple of time to get more info.

Comment: If you print the contents of the exception it will probably tell you exactly what's wrong.  Type `po $eax` in the debug window when you have the exception frame selected.  The assembly of the throw exception method doesn't help us at all.

Comment: Please, when you show an exception traceback, show the one in the console window, via copy/paste.  It's pretty much impossible to read those images.

Comment: (What is the actual text of the actual exception??)

Comment: I don't have it up anymore but it indicated that NSDate was the culprit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me you have `NSDate` type in the dictionary?
eg:

```
"PA_CREATE_DT" = "2014-01-03 05:00:00 +0000";
```

you might want to convert such to string before doing the json serilization.

such as this:

```
NSString *stringDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", nsdateDate];
```

Comment: @Zaph I am suspecting the dictionary dump automatically convert it to a pretty string.

Comment: JSON does not have a Date type, only Number, String, Boolean, Array, Object (which is just a dictionary). Thus it is a String.

Comment: That was it, dang it not sure how I missed it. Thanks

Comment: @Zaph yes, thats why I suspect he has a NSDate in the dictionary, since it seems he's creating a JSON serialization for posting to some web service instead of deserializing one

Comment: Note that the most common way to transmit a date in JSON is as a UNIX timestamp:  `(long)([nsDateObject timeItervalSince1970] * 1000)`.  The other common way is [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

Comment: And note that the `stringWithFormat` approach above is simply an expensive way to invoke `description` on the date object.